# Polymer-1.0 is there a paper-dialog dismiss event?

Tags: polymer-1.0

Is there a `dismiss` event for paper-dialog? I tried `dialog-dismiss` but it doesn't listen to ESC keyboard press. I tried `iron-overlay-close` but this one bugs if there is another iron-overlay within the dialog (such as an iron-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific `dismiss` event for `paper-dialog` because it inherits the iron-overlay behaviour. However, you could create a custom event to trigger a dialog-dismiss:

```
// Fire a custom event 
this.fire('custom-dialog-dismiss');

// Listen to the event on an element OR add a listener
<my-element on-custom-dialog-dismiss="_handleDismiss"></my-element>
...or...
listeners: {
  'custom-dialog-dismiss': '_handleDismiss'
}

// Then handle the action
_handleDismiss: function(e) {
  this.$.myDialog.close();
}
```